# How can I misuse the information of DCE service enumeration?

Tags: windows, vulnerability-scanners, audit, metasploit, enumeration

Nessus reports almost on any Windows machine "DCE service enumaration". With the metasploit module `tcp_dcerpc_auditor` I get the following information:

```
192.168.1.23 - UUID 99fcfec4-5260-101b-bbcb-00aa0021347a 0.0 OPEN VIA 135 ACCESS GRANTED 0000000somelongnumber0000
192.168.1.23 - UUID afa8bd80-7d8a-11c9-bef4-08002b102989 1.0 OPEN VIA 135 ACCESS GRANTED 00000somelongnumber0000
```

In the nessus finding it says it could be used for information gathering. But how exactly? Is there a way to use the UUID?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check [this](http://www.offensive-security.com/metasploit-unleashed/Scanner_DCERPC_Auxiliary_Modules) out. An attacker can see what services are running on the machine. This information can be very useful for planning and launching an attack.